# Dynamically Add User Controls - And Pass and Take Data from them

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I need a way to dynamically add user controls to a page, then pass data to those user controls. Then, on a button click, grab all the data from those controls. There will be textboxes, and radio buttons, and dropdownlists and so on in the controls. Can anyone recommend a convenient or efficient way of doing this? Preferably in a way that uses methods built into ASP.net and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a dialog that you can reuse to display or post values
IF your trying to add/view data